# Inserting WebComponents as content into Monaco Editor

Tags: editor, web-component, monaco-editor

Is there a way to insert a WebComponent into the Monaco Editor?  I'd like to be able to drop an HTML WebComponent onto the editor and the WebComponent would be interactive.  For example, I could drop a timestamp component onto the editor that looks like [00:00:00.000] but the hours, minutes, seconds etc are interactive, i.e. can use up and down arrows.  Behind the scenes, I know Monaco is a hidden textarea and I'd therefore like to expose something like an innerText value from the component so that Monaco just receives the text.  That's one direction - on reload I'd like it to detect the timestamp values and render out Webcomponents preset with the values.

Fingers crossed!  If this is not possible - I have seen that Monaco has IContentWidgets and wonder if this is somethings that could be used?